# Operation not allowed after ResultSet close 9030

Tags: mysql, resultset, sqlexception

I am getting Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed Error in my code. My code is given below. I am using a method to calculate salary and then I set this salary in the object.

```
       try {
            while (rs.next()){
                int sala = 0;
                int sa = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(4));
                int lea = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(5));
                String name = rs.getString(2);
                sala = getsalary(name, fromdate, todate, lea, sa);

                s.setEmpid(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)));
                s.setEmpname(rs.getString(2));
                s.setEmpcat(rs.getString(3));
                s.setSalary(sala);
                s.setLeaves(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(5)));

                sal.add(s);
                s = new salary();
                rowCount++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The EXCEPTION is because I believe you are receiving the ResultSet in the Parameter of the method called from some other method.
You have closed the connection there so here you are getting this exception.
Please show us the complete method with the parameters